# Why doesn't my parent-child component relationship result in a rendering loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's assume I have a parent component in which I am displaying a chart component. This chart component takes in a time series data and plots it if the data satisfies a certain criteria, if not it passes an error message to the parent through a errorMessage state handler passed by parent to child.

Now if the time series does not validate the condition then the child would update the errorMessage which would cause re-rendering of the child, and would again lead to child executing the code and again updating the errorMessage leading to infinite loop.

Two questions here:

1. Theoretically based on my understanding this should happen, however there is no infinite loop rendering when I try it on my machine
2. What is the best way to show these error messages, given the error message is being maintained by the parent and the error can occur in the child too

Refer to the pseudo-code below

```
const parent = () => {
  const [error,setError] = useState(null);
  return (
           <div>
               <Child data={[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]} onError={setError}/>
                <ErrorDisplay error={error}/>
           </div> );  
}

const child = ({data, onError}) => {
  if (!someCondition(data))
         onError("There is some error")
  return (
           <Chart data={data}/>
 
);}
```

Comment: For a start, both `parent` and `child` should be initially-capitalized, since JSX relies on that to know they're components, not HTML tag names.

Comment: Shouldn't `child`/`Child` **not** render `Chart` when there's an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Gabriele Petrioli points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701058/157247), provided nothing else changes, you won't be in an *endless* cycle because a state update that changes to exactly the same value doesn't cause a re-render. But by default you'd still get the child doing the work twice (once to find the error, then again when the parent re-renders to show the error and the child gets called again).

There are at least a couple of ways to avoid that duplication:

1. Hold the error state in `Child`, not `Parent`, and don't recompute `error` if `data` is unchanged.
2. [Memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)-ize the `Child` so the function doesn't get called again when its props haven't changed.

Here's a version of #2 that relies on array identity (that is, it won't run `Child` again if the **same array** is provided to it):

```
const Child = React.memo(({data, onError}) => {
    if (!someCondition(data)) {
        onError("There is some error")
        return null; // Or whatever
    }
    return (
        <Chart data={data}/>
    );
});
```

A more defensive version could check to see whether the new array is *equivalent* to the previous one, even if they aren't the same array:

```
const childPropsAreEqual = (prevProps, currProps) => {
    // Where `deepEquals` is a function that does a deep equivalence
    // check on the array
    return deepEquals(prevProps.data, currProps.data);
};
const Child = React.memo(({data, onError}) => {
    if (!someCondition(data)) {
        onError("There is some error")
        return null; // Or whatever
    }
    return (
        <Chart data={data}/>
    );
}, childPropsAreEqual); // <== Note providing an "are equal" function
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you do not experience the loop is because of

> [Bailing out of a state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)
>
> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

Comment: Good point. By default, the child would still do the work twice (once to find the error, then again when the parent re-renders with the error), but at least not *more* than that. :-)